# Passing Id from CreateView to another function after creating the object

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, create-view

I am creating a Payment object using Django `CreateView` then I want to pass the `id` of this object to another view function to make and display some calculations on another template. how can i do that?

views.py:

```
class CreatePayment(CreateView):
    template_name = "inventory/new_payment.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inventory:payments_page')
    model = Payments
    fields = ('payment_number', 'customer','agent', 'amount')
```

html:

```
<body>

<form action="{% url 'inventory:new_payment'%}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}

    <button type="submit", value="Add">Add</button>
</form>

</body>
```

urls:

```
url(r'newpayment/$', CreatePayment.as_view(), name='new_payment')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parameter to your other view and url and use `get_success_url`:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inventory:payments_page', {'id': self.object.pk})
    return success_url
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it by overriding the `get_success_url` in `CreateView` like this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('inventory:transaction', args=(self.object.id,))
```

Comment: made by mistake